# cannot "npm install -g truffle" in PowerShell - #ERROR (cannot find module 'original-require')

Tags: truffle, private-blockchain, solc, windows, truffle-console

What's this error? How can I resolve

[image: TRUFFLE INSTALLATION ERROR]

Comment: Have you tried: `npm install original-require`?

Answer (score 0):

I used to develop smart contracts using Windows but last year changed to Windows Subsystem for Linux as kept running into issues with tools that wouldn't work with Windows.

Recommend considering using Windows Subsystem for Linux:
https://davidburela.wordpress.com/2017/05/12/how-to-install-truffle-testrpc-on-ubuntu-or-windows-10-with-windows-subsystem-for-linux/